# Creating a select form element with multiple preselected options

Tags: forms

How could I create a select form element that has more than one options selected as default options? Does the form API allow it?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it my self using this [example](http://drupal.org/node/265613) Default value is used to set multiple options preselected. It should be array of list for preselection